# Creating a Quaternary-Tree in python based on random Boolean value

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I am using a random seed to generate boolean values that determine the existence of the four children of a node. For context this is used to generate the values for randomly generated rooms in a game I am working on.
The class to do this is here:

```
class Room:
def __init__(self, roomID):

    # the initial room @ c/r with seed roomIDs [c][r]
    random.seed(roomID)

    # the value of the room is equal to the seed that generated it
    self.id = roomID

    # use the seed to determine if it has rooms attached
    self.north = bool(random.getrandbits(1))
    self.south = bool(random.getrandbits(1))
    self.east = bool(random.getrandbits(1))
    self.west = bool(random.getrandbits(1))

def insert(self, roomIds, c, r):
    # Compare the new value with the parent node
    if self.north == True:
        self.north.insert = Room(roomIds[c][r + 1])
    if self.south == True:
        self.south.insert = Room(roomIds[c][r - 1])
    if self.east == True:
        self.east.insert = Room(roomIds[c + 1][r])
    if self.west == True:
        self.west.insert = Room(roomIds[c - 1][r])
```

RoomID is equal to the row/column in RowIDs corresponding to that room
So for example if we had a 2x2 array.

`1 2
 2 5`

The roomIDs[0][0] would be 1 and this is the RoomID for that room column 0 row 0.

My function to generate the map is as follows

```
def generateMap(Head, RoomIds, c, r, size):
if size <= 0:
    return

if Head.north == True:
    try:
        Head.north = Room(roomID=RoomIds[c + 1][r])
    except:
        pass
    tmp = Head.north
    return generateMap(tmp, RoomIds, c + 1, r, size - 1)
if Head.south == True:
    try:
        Head.north = Room(roomID=RoomIds[c - 1][r])
    except:
        pass
    tmp = Head.north
    return generateMap(tmp, RoomIds, c - 1, r, size - 1)
if Head.east == True:
    try:
        Head.north = Room(roomID=RoomIds[c][r + 1])
    except:
        pass
    tmp = Head.north
    return generateMap(tmp, RoomIds, c, r + 1, size - 1)
if Head.west == True:
    try:
        Head.north = Room(roomID=RoomIds[c][r - 1])
    except:
        pass
    tmp = Head.north
    return generateMap(tmp, RoomIds, c, r - 1, size - 1)
```

If the child north is true I want it to recursively add a node there (with the same boolean values) and follow that path to the end. This is the same for the south, east and west. The row and column changes depending on what direction we're working with.

I call them like this

```
head = mapGen.Room(roomID=roomIDs[5][5])
rooms = mapGen.generateMap(head, roomIDs, 5, 5, size)
```

Where size is the total size of the array. And 5,5 is just an arbitrary starting room.
This implementation works sort of. It generates the correct number of rooms but the RoomIDs cycle between two values. Here is some sample output:

```
Room: @ 9 is 28664435753962367559
Room: @ 8 is 21687111371302414893
Room: @ 7 is 28664435753962367559
Room: @ 6 is 21687111371302414893
Room: @ 5 is 28664435753962367559
Room: @ 4 is 21687111371302414893
Room: @ 3 is 28664435753962367559
Room: @ 2 is 21687111371302414893
Room: @ 1 is 28664435753962367559
Room: @ 0 is 61454798153344042283
```

I was wondering what is happening in my logic that the seeds for each room are always the same. Thank you in advance for your assistance